# Jquery change images with scrolling

Tags: jquery, parallax

i have a folder with 400 images named in continuous numbers(1,2,3..) (converted a video into images). i want to increase or change the window background with those images in the folder with scroll position change. i'm a newbie any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the scroll event

```
jQuery(window).on("scroll",function() {
   if( some condition is true ) { //do some kind of check to see if you are
                                  //far enough down to require a change
      var lastbg = jQuery("body").css("background-image");
      //do some manipulation to get the last number
      jQuery("body").css({backgroundImage:"url(urltonewimage)"});
   }
});
```

Comment: you dont use a loop, you just get the lastbg which gives you the last file used, lop off the part that is the number and increment it and then use it to create the new url for the next image, or store the current index you are using for the file number and increment it and use it. If you dont know how to do these then you need more help then we can give, google String manipulation, substr, split etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) to calculate how far it had scrolled and then change the images accordingly.

```
jQuery(window).on("scroll",function() {
   var n = $(window).scrollTop(); // Set scroll number
   if (n <= 0) { var n = 0; } // Check that value isn't smaller than 0
   jQuery("body").css({backgroundImage:"url(imagename"+n+"});
});
```

That would probably do it, but I haven't tested it.